# load() specific href after clicking a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have this JS code:

```
$('.tile').on('click', function() {    
    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').css('backgroundColor','#4c7fb5');
        $('.metro .tile-area .user-id').css('backgroundColor','#4c7fb5');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load("company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);
});
```

I also have some HTML `<a>` which are buttons and they are all called tile

I want to load the specific `href` defined in the `<a>` as seen here with two of them:

```
<a class="tile double bg-tile7color animated seven flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content image">
        <div class="padding10">
            <h2 class="fg-white ntm">Cost</h2>
            <p class="fg-white ntm">Pricing and Proposals</p>
        </div>
        <div class="brand">
            <div class="label"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="tile bg-tile8color animated eight flipInX" data-click="transform">
    <div class="tile-content icon">
        <span>
            <img src="images/mthc/referrals.png">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="brand">
        <div class="text-center padding10 ntp">
            <p class="fg-white">Referrals</p></div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

How do I change the JS to load whatever they have in their `href`'s and not what is currently specified in the `.load()` part of the function? Currently it's  loading `company-overview.html`.  While that is the case I will also need to make the color changes unique to the buttons so is there any way to integrate this change into the s ?

Comment: Your `a`s don't have `href` attributes.

Comment: ook but even if they did the JS .load("company-overview.html") would overide it wouldn't it ? How would i replace that .load to have something like .load(the href i will put in to each a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace `load("company-overview.html")` with `.load($(this).attr('href')` to reference the `href` [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) of the current/target `.tile` being clicked:

```
$('.tile').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();  // stop the default link click behavior
    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson').css('backgroundColor','#4c7fb5');
        $('.metro .tile-area .user-id').css('backgroundColor','#4c7fb5');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load($(this).attr('href'));
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: yes but it still needs to load into the .tile-group.main instead of loading a new page altogether

Comment: Updated to stop the default behavior

Comment: perhaps it is academic anyway as I would also need the css color changes to be specific to each tile maybe i should repeat the function for each button

Comment: ... I guess changing .tile at the top of the function to (.tile.tile1) for the onclick bit and then copy and paste the entire function 7 times (7 buttons) but changing the id's 1through to 7 would do it but seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `this` keyword in the click handler to refer to the clicked element. From that you can retrieve the `href` attribute:

```
$('.tile').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.metro .tile-area-darkCrimson, .metro .tile-area .user-id').css('backgroundColor','#4c7fb5');
        $(".tile-group.main").css({ marginLeft:"-40px", width: "1080px"}).load($(this).prop('href'));
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately while that worked it just loaded the page as a new page and didn't do the first part of loading it into .tile-group.main    ... any ideas

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `preventDefault()` to stop the default link behaviour. I updated my answer for you.

Comment: that doesn't seem to load the content into it although the flipOutX function part does work ?? hmmm weird

Comment: perhaps it is academic anyway as I would also need the css color changes to be specific to each tile maybe i should repeat the function for each button